# how to get printer icons

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, printing

sorry this may look like a duplicate question because a similar question was posted but the answers which were given weren't complete. i want to create a list of available printers stating the status of the printer and the icon associated with each printer. at this point am able to get the list and their associated states, but where am failing is getting the icons. from the earlier posted question the answer involved using SHGetFileInfo, but when i tried it no icons were returned. i suspect there was something i need to do before calling SHGetFileInfo because the answer included a statement which involved combining two PIDLs, now because it wasn't actual code but a comment i couldn't fully understand how to implement it. [here is a link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224169/what-is-the-folder-location-of-installed-printers?rq=1)

```
for (int i=0; i < dwReturned; i++)
{
    HICON hIcon = NULL;

    LPITEMIDLIST pidlPrinters = NULL;
    LPITEMIDLIST pidl = NULL;
    LPENUMIDLIST pEnum = NULL;
    LPSHELLFOLDER pDesktopFolder = NULL;
    IShellFolder* psfPrinters = NULL;
    STRRET strName;
    TCHAR pszDisplayName[MAX_PATH];
    HRESULT hr;
    SHFILEINFO sfi;

    hr = SHGetFolderLocation(m_pParentWnd->m_hWnd, CSIDL_PRINTERS, 0, 0, &pidlPrinters);

    if(hr == S_OK)
    {
        hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&pDesktopFolder);
    }

    if(hr == S_OK)
    {
        hr = pDesktopFolder->BindToObject(pidlPrinters, 0, IID_IShellFolder, reinterpret_cast<void**> 
             (&psfPrinters));
    }

    if(hr == S_OK)
    {
        hr = psfPrinters->EnumObjects(m_pParentWnd->m_hWnd, SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, 
            &pEnum);
    }

    if(hr == S_OK)
    {
        while (pEnum->Next(1, &pidl, 0) == S_OK)
        {
            psfPrinters->GetDisplayNameOf(pidl,SHGDN_NORMAL, &strName);

            StrRetToBuf(&strName, pidl, pszDisplayName, MAX_PATH);

            //pInfo is PRINTER_INFO_2 *

            if (_wcsicmp(pszDisplayName, pInfo[i].pPrinterName) == 0)
            {
                SHGetFileInfo((LPCTSTR)pidl, 0, &sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO),  SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_ICON | 
                SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME | SHGFI_TYPENAME); 
                hIcon = sfi.hIcon;
            }

            IMalloc* Malloc = NULL;
            SHGetMalloc(&Malloc);
            Malloc->Free(pidl);
            Malloc->Release();
       }

       pDesktopFolder->Release();
       pEnum->Release();

       //Some other code
    }
}
```

Comment: `IEnumObjects::Next` returns a relative pidl, you need to combine that with the full pidl of the parent folder to get something `SHGetFileInfo` can work with. It's like having "file.txt" and adding it to "c:\folder\" to get a full pathname. You can use the `ILCombine` function to do that.

Comment: thanks for the answer, though i still can't get the icons. it is now showing this "First-chance exception at 0x758F35D2 (KernelBase.dll) in GlowWindow.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x80040155, 0x00000052, 0x03E5F3F8).
onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\marshal.cxx(1111)\combase.dll!753F49E8: (caller: 7538747C) ReturnHr(19) tid(1348) 80040155 Interface not registered
    Msg:[Failed to marshal with IID={000214EB-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}] " on the output window

Comment: No idea sorry. Looks like a different question though.

Comment: any way i think the ILCombine function did the trick, i just need to find a solution to that exception am getting

Comment: First-chance exceptions are not a problem as long as something handles the exception. If your program doesn't crash I'd say don't worry about it.

Comment: @user12655962 If the answer help you solve this issue you can [**accept**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it. Feel free let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf` to extract the icon, the following is an example you can have a try.

```
            psfPrinters->GetDisplayNameOf(pidl, SHGDN_NORMAL, &strName);

            IExtractIcon* eIcon = NULL;
            hr = psfPrinters->GetUIObjectOf(NULL, 1, (LPCITEMIDLIST*)&pidl, IID_IExtractIcon, NULL, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&eIcon));
            if (hr == S_OK)
            {
                WCHAR iconFileLocation[200];
                int index;
                UINT flag = 0;
                hr = eIcon->GetIconLocation(NULL, iconFileLocation, sizeof(iconFileLocation), &index, &flag);
                if (hr == S_OK)
                {
                    UINT size = 100;
                    eIcon->Extract(iconFileLocation, index, &hIcon, NULL, size);
                    if (hr == S_OK)
                    {
                        // Draw printer icon on client area for checking purpose
                        DrawIcon(hdc, xNew, y, hIcon);
                        xNew += size;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Sample output of above code:

[image]